# git fetch failed "refs/remotes/origin/pr/34 tracks both"

Tags: git

I am new to git and I am stuck on a git fetch (I have more experience on TFS & SVN, so any analogy is welcome :)

So I found a project on Github that I forked :

- source project ([Xposed Tinted StatusBar](https://github.com/MohammadAG/Xposed-Tinted-Status-Bar))
- mine is [here](https://github.com/MrLuje/Xposed-Tinted-Status-Bar)

I made a few check-in, also made a git pull to fetch latest changes from the source and at some point, I think I hit the Synchronize button (I'm using the AndroidStudio BTW) and I got lost from here.

It generated this [commit](https://github.com/MrLuje/Xposed-Tinted-Status-Bar/commit/7e958cc2a525375c075cbaece7eb0a8571524a97) that I don't really understand and from here, it seems that I am not able to fetch latest additions from source anymore (the 4 last changes on black source)

I am getting the following error on git fetch :

> fatal: refs/remotes/origin/pr/34 tracks both refs/pull/34/head and
>   refs/heads/pr/34

https://github.com/MohammadAG/Xposed-Tinted-Status-Bar/network
[image: Why I can't get the 3 latest changes ?]

Thanks

Comment: What does `git config --get-all remotes.origin.fetch` print?

Comment: Hum, nothing... the command does not print anything

Comment: Oops, sorry, typo/braino, it's `remote.origin.fetch` (singular with remote here).  What I'm thinking is there may be two lines that map the same remote ref to two different local refs.

Comment: Yep, much better :)

+refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short version: the branch named `pr/34` on the remote, becomes your `origin/pr/34`.  But the ref named `refs/pull/34/head` on the remote, also becomes your `origin/pr/34`.  But they can't both become that, so git complains and quits.  Whatever is setting up the branch mapping is not playing well with whatever is setting up the pull-request branches on github (but I don't know anything about those two pieces of software).

It *may* (I don't know) be reasonable to delete the `+refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*` `fetch` configuration line.  Alternatively, you could map these to some other local ref-name-space, such as `refs/pullreqs/origin/*` (but such a reference name is somewhat inconvenient to type in).  If every pull request is going to create *both* `refs/heads/pr/number` *and* `refs/pull/number/head` on github, I'd go ahead and remove the one configuration line.

---

Longer explanation of source of problem follows.  Given this:

> ```
> +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
> +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
> +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
> ```

as output from `git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch`, I can explain what's going wrong.  "How to fix it" depends on the results you want.

Each output line here is a "refspec", which consists of three parts: the `+`, a name on the left of the `:`, and a name on the right of the `:`.  One `*` is allowed in both names, and it works sort of (but not exactly) like `*` matching in file-names, e.g., `*.c`, `*.py`, etc., with the second `*` then using whatever the first `*` matched.  It should be obvious below, anyway.

(The last line is redundant and thus harmless, it just makes the match happen twice.)

So, let's see what the above means for the ref-names `refs/pull/34/head` and `refs/heads/pr/34`, both of which are present in the remote named `origin` (on github).

For `refs/pull/34/head`: this matches just the first refspec.  The `*` part matches the `34`.  The right-hand-side of that refspec says to rewrite this to read `refs/remotes/origin/pr/*`, so the result is:

```
refs/remotes/origin/pr/34
```

Now let's tackle `refs/heads/pr/34`.  This does not match the first refspec, but it does match the second.  The `*` part matches `pr/34`.  The right-hand-side of that refspec says to rewrite it as `refs/remotes/origin/*`, so the result is:

```
refs/remotes/origin/pr/34
```

Note how two *different* names on `origin` have mapped to the same *final* name in your local repository.  Git does not know whether to set your local `refs/remotes/origin/pr/34` equal to the first one, or the second one, as seen on `origin`.

To make the error go away, you must either discard the unwanted "extra" match entirely, or change the rewriting rules so that the two different remote `refs/whatever`s become two *different* local `refs/remotes/origin/whatever`s.  That means you need to change the `fetch =` lines in your git config file.

I don't know what result you want, so I can't say how to rewrite them.  (And, I don't know what created these in the first place—a normal `git clone` creates just one `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` entry.  Something else added the redundant entry, and the one for `refs/pull/*/head`.  It's that something-else that broke things.  Well, that, plus the fact that something created `refs/heads/pr/34` on github.)

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue when I pulled a PR locally, made changes to the PR, then pushed to the remote. When trying to fetch future PR's, I got a similar error. To fix I deleted the new local branch (after merging) and then deleting the branch off the remote (GitHub in my case).

Comment: Yep, that just happened to our team too. It's recommended if you're going to change a PR that you create a new branch from it (that's why it alerts you to "headless" mode) so there won't be a naming conflict when you push